# Why routes declared in another module giving error in Nanoexpress.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nanoexpress

I am using nanoexpress and routes are not working properly when declared them in other module.

Here is my index.js:

```
var nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress');
const router = require('./router/routes');

const app = nanoexpress();

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3100).then(
    res => {
        console.log('Server Started');
    }
);
```

Here is my routes.js:

```
var nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress');

const app = nanoexpress();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send({ status: 'ok' });
});
module.exports = app;
```

There is no compilation error but getting this runtime error when called this route:

```
Server Started


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: receiver.IsJSFunction().
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffd4fc66590
 1: 0xa77121  [node]
 2: 0x19e0405 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0xeccfe2 v8::internal::JSReceiver::GetCreationContext() [node]
 4: 0xb8e868 v8::Object::CreationContext() [node]
 5: 0x974f13 node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*, node::async_context) [node]
 6: 0x7fad54414fca  [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
 7: 0x7fad5440fab8  [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
 8: 0x7fad54416ff0  [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
 9: 0x7fad5441703e  [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
10: 0x7fad54416e98  [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
11: 0x7fad54408305  [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
12: 0x7fad54416044 uWS::HttpContext<false>::init()::{lambda(us_socket_t*, char*, int)#1}::__invoke(us_socket_t*, char*, int) [/mnt/1F8376FA6D76E846/IdeaProjects/Tests/Nano-Express-Test/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws_linux_x64_72.node]
13: 0x133eb48  [node]
14: 0x132cbab uv_run [node]
15: 0xa4c2e3 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [node]
16: 0x9dad48 node::Start(int, char**) [node]
17: 0x7fad55f3fb97 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
18: 0x973595  [node]
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Because you are using wrong syntax. On simple version not possible use as express.Router()

Answer (score -1):

nanoexpress author here.

Try nanoexpress Pro as now it's Free and supports `Router()` you can use express like syntax.